# How to create a for-loop in relation to value obtained via Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, loops, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

Variables

```
chrome_path = 'chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
driver.get("https://gibiru.com/")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.form-control.has-feedback.has-clear').click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.form-control.has-feedback.has-clear').send_keys("lfc")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.form-control.has-feedback.has-clear').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/main/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]").click()
time.sleep(2)
```

I have this try-stratement, which works perfect, but needs to be looped arcordding to the value of page_length, which is equal to 10 in this situation.

```
try:
    #1st page 
    page_length = len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.gsc-resultsRoot.gsc-tabData.gsc-tabdActive div.gsc-cursor-box.gs-bidi-start-align div.gsc-cursor div.gsc-cursor-page"))
    index_count = 0
    current_page = int(page_length) - int(index_count)
    print("Number of availables pages : "+str(current_page)) #Print = 10

    find_href = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img.gs-image.gs-image-scalable')
    with open("txt.txt", "a") as textFile:
        for my_href in find_href:
            textFile.write(str(my_href.get_attribute("src")) + "\n")
            print(my_href.get_attribute("src"))
    
    index_count += 1
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(100,document.body.scrollHeight);")
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div['+str(index_count)+']').click()
    time.sleep(2)

    #2nd page
    current_page = int(page_length) - int(index_count)
    print("Number of availables pages : "+str(current_page)) #Print = 10

    find_href = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img.gs-image.gs-image-scalable')
    with open("txt.txt", "a") as textFile:
        for my_href in find_href:
            textFile.write(str(my_href.get_attribute("src")) + "\n")
            print(my_href.get_attribute("src"))

    index_count += 1
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(100,document.body.scrollHeight);")
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div['+str(index_count)+']').click()
    time.sleep(2)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    driver.quit()
```

But I seek help in regards to creating a for-loop. That can do what the try-statement can, but in fewer lines of code. This is what I'm thinking of :

```
for x in page_array_number:
    index_count = 0
    current_page = int(page_length) - int(index_count)
    print("Number of availables pages : "+str(current_page))
    find_href = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img.gs-image.gs-image-scalable')
    with open("txt.txt", "a") as textFile:
        for my_href in find_href:
            textFile.write(str(my_href.get_attribute("src")) + "\n")
            print(my_href.get_attribute("src"))
    
    print("Counter is before : "+str(index_count))
    index_count += 1
    print("Counter is after : "+str(index_count))
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(100,document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div['+str(index_count)+']').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    if index_count == page_length:
        print("Done scraping urls from "+str(page_length)+" pages")
        break
```

The output I be getting is as such: It's seems like it is the counter that is the problem, it doesnt add 1 on for every loop.

[image: Output]

Comment: Can you TLDR the issue and explain what exactly you need in few words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with this for loop :

```
for index, item in enumerate(page_array_number):
        print(index)
        current_page = int(page_length) - int(index)
        print("Number of availables pages : "+str(current_page))
        index = index+1
        print("Counter is after : "+str(index))
        find_href = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img.gs-image.gs-image-scalable')
        with open("txt.txt", "a") as textFile:
            for my_href in find_href:
                textFile.write(str(my_href.get_attribute("src")) + "\n")
                print(my_href.get_attribute("src"))
        
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(100,document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(2)
        if index == 1:
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div['+str(index+1)+']').click()
            time.sleep(2)
        elif index > 1:
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div['+str(index)+']').click()
            time.sleep(2)
        elif index == page_length:
            print("Done scraping urls from "+str(page_length)+" pages")
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

`len()` returns an integer, which is not an iterable object. I would use the `enumerate()` method, which returns the index and value of the next item in the iterable. `enumerate()` is also faster in many cases.

```
pages = driver.find_elements()
page_length = len(pages)
for index, value in enumerate(pages):
    current_page = page_length - index
    ...
```

Also, the last two lines of code is redundant. If `index_count == page_length`, then that is the last iteration of the loop and will exit anyway.

Some other notes: if you are looping and don't need the loop variable, replace it with an underscore. In the above code, since we don't need the variable `value`:

```
for index, _ in enumerate(pages):
    # This is clear that we don't use the values contained in pages
    current_page = page_length - index
    ...
```

Lastly, you can often get errors like `NoSuchAttributeException` and `ElementNotInteractableException` due to variations in page load and JS execution times. I would suggest encapsulating selenium code that interacts with the web page in `try` `except` statements.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question with output from ternimal and new code. It's works fine  as is, but the counter doenst count +1 for every loop.

Comment: That is because you are rewriting it every loop. As soon as it finishes one iteration, it goes to the top and runs `index_count = 0`. Move this line of code to before the `for` statement. However, `enumerate()` is really the best way to handle getting the loop index.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for the explanation. I see now that the index_count = 0 should come before the for statement. But I also get why enumerate() is more suitanable. Cool.